# C# Implementing and converting interfaces

Tags: c#

Ive a class that implement the IMarcas interface:

```
  public class BaseQuestao : IMarcas
    {
        public string TxtMarca
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

Where TxtMarca property is an assignture from that interface.

Problem is that when i try to execute follow code is says that BasesQuestao is NOT IMarcas:

```
BaseQuestao bs = new BaseQuestao();
IMarcas brand =  bs as IMarcas;
if (brand != null)
{
    bs.TxtMarca = "voila";
}
```

Any ideias?

Comment: you shouldn't be checking bs for null, you should be checking brand.

Comment: A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would really help, as the above is fine.

Comment: Perhaps the interface is not declared public? The above code is fine, the problem must lie somewhere else. Most obvious things to look for include: interface not declared public. namespace issues, missing reference. Please post the whole code including the definition of the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, you're using the wrong variable (`bs` instead of `brand`) - but it would have worked either way.

Here's an example with the code corrected:

```
using System;

public interface IMarcas
{
    string TxtMarca { get; set; }
}

public class BaseQuestao : IMarcas
{
    public string TxtMarca
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        BaseQuestao bs = new BaseQuestao();
        IMarcas brand =  bs as IMarcas;
        if (brand != null)
        {
            brand.TxtMarca = "voila";
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }
    }
}
```

and even with the original code:

```
if (bs != null)
{
    bs.TxtMarca = "voila";
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

... it's still fine.

Comment: Im sorry but even checking brand variable,it still says that is NULL

Comment: @user257234: Well my working example includes all the code you've posted, which means it has to be in some code you *haven't* posted. Please come up with a similar short-but-complete program, but one which *does* fail.

Comment: Can you step through the debugger and watch it play out? At some point your bs is getting set to null somehow. The code you posted isn't enough for us to determine what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

After you cast `bs` to an `IMarcas` as `brand`, you then check if `bs` is null, not `brand`. You should check if `brand` is null to see if the cast succeeded.

Other than that it should work just fine. If it still doesn't work, please post more code/context.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (brand != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your code, as the above code is fine